# Does God Laugh?

Tags: nature-of-god

I am really interested in whether God ever laughs? Lots of people say that he doesn't or that he is all doom and gloom. BUt I am sure that the God of the Bible laughs. What do other people think?

Comment: @Andrew C, the question has been asked here many times in many different ways. You may want to use the search feature (located at top right corner of page with a magnified glass icon in the field). Search for 'God laugh' and you will see results of where others have asked it before. One popular form of the question can be located [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3304/does-god-have-a-sense-of-humor-does-he-laugh), on this site. Click on this link.

Answer (score 2):

[Scripture says that He can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EKal.jpg), though I don't think it shows a specific time when he actually does:

> **Psalm 59:3,8 ESV** For behold, they lie in wait for my life; fierce men stir up strife against me ... But you, O Lord, **laugh** at them; you hold all the nations in derision.
>
> **Proverbs 1:24-29 ESV** Because I have called and you refused to listen, have stretched out my hand and no one has heeded, because you have ignored all my counsel and would have none of my reproof, I also will **laugh** at your calamity; I will mock when terror strikes you, when terror strikes you like a storm and your calamity comes like a whirlwind, when distress and anguish come upon you. Then they will call upon me, but I will not answer; they will seek me diligently but will not find me. Because they hated knowledge and did not choose the fear of the Lord,

These two passages ↑ show God doing a derisive laugh which probably isn't what you're looking for.

However this passage ↓ gives great insight on the heart of God.

> **Ecclesiastes 3:1-8 ESV** For everything there is a season, and a time for every matter under heaven: a time to be born, and a time to die; a time to plant, and a time to pluck up what is planted; a time to kill, and a time to heal; a time to break down, and a time to build up; a time to weep, and a time to **laugh**; a time to mourn, and a time to dance;a time to cast away stones, and a time to gather stones together; a time to embrace, and a time to refrain from embracing; a time to seek, and a time to lose; a time to keep, and a time to cast away; a time to tear, and a time to sew; a time to keep silence, and a time to speak; a time to love, and a time to hate; a time for war, and a time for peace.

God is shown to have done all things in this list (kill, heal, break down, build up, mourn, dance, etc...), so it stands to reason that he also laughs.

Comment: how did you add the vertical arrows to the text of your answer?

Comment: @Greenman alt + 24 = ↑. alt + 25 = ↓. Or you could try prayer and fasting.